# Eclipse 3.7, m2eclipse & losing artifacts after changing pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, pom.xml, artifacts

I have a bit of a problem with Eclipse and Maven for a few months. After changing the `pom.xml`, Eclipse is losing all artifacts and getting this exception in my Maven console:

```
Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
```

Eclipse doesn't find any artifacts. My workaround is to close Eclipse, run `mvn clean install` on the command line and start Eclipse. This workaround works without any problems, but is not really the right way. How can I fix this issue?

I'm running Eclipse 3.7 and the newest m2eclipse(-extra), Windows 7 64bit with JDK 1.6.0.24.

Comment: I was figthing a lot with Maven and Eclipse and finally found SpringRoo which helps a lot with maven issues. STS has all necessary plugins and Roo embedded. I dont know what is the nature of your project but you may consider it. 

Sometimes deleting local maven cache and downloading all dependencies again solves an issue.

Comment: Go to the user list for m2eclipse for support on m2eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it builds ok when Maven is explicitly run - yes?
Have you tried right-clicking on the project and selecting

```
Maven..Update Project Configuration
```

and

```
Maven..Update Dependencies?
```

If not, that's likely to solve your problem.

Comment: At the moment i have the problem, that one project lose all dependencies. I tried mvn clean (from eclipse), Update Project Configuration and also Update Dependencies, nothing helps :/ All artefacts are in my local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also running

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

I had a similar issue and I ran that, the refreshed the project in eclipse and everything worked fine.

Comment: Yes, i try this now, but the same problem :/